# Erase in multiset

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, erase, multiset

I'm new with STL containers, and right now i'm having some problems working with Multiset. 
The problem is with the following two collections:

```
vector<DataReference*> referenceCol;
multiset<DataCount, DataCountSortingCriterion> orderedCol;
```

orderedCol mantains some data elements that have two public integer fields: id and count. I'm ordering that structure by the count elements. I may need to increment and decrement the count field from that elements, so, in order to maintain the ordering, i'm using a second collection (referenceCol) which is indexed by the id field and holds a reference (iterator) to the orderedCol collection, so every moment i need to refresh the count i can erase the element from orderedCol quickly (by refering to it in referenceCol), refresh it, and insert it again in its proper place according to the ordering.

The referenceCol is created in the constructor of my class, and has two fields: validReference (bool) that indicates whether the iterator reference is valid or not, and the multiset<....>::iterator variable.

The following methods handle the increment and decrement operations that affect these two collections:

```
void SomeClass::decrementCount(int index)
{
    multiset<DataCount, DataCountSortingCriterion>::iterator it = referenceCol[index]->it;
    DataCount dop = *it;
    orderedCol.erase(it);   

    dop.count--;
    if (dop.count > 0) {
        it = orderedCol.insert(dop);
        referenceCol[index]->it = it;
    }
    else {
        referenceCol[index]->validRef = false;
    }
}

void SomeClass::incrementCount(int index)
{
    DataCount dop;
    multiset<DataCount, DataCountSortingCriterion>::iterator it;


    if (referenceCol[index]->validRef) {
        it = referenceCol[index]->it;
        dop = *it;

        orderedCol.erase(it); <--------- BOOM!
        dop.count++;
    }
    else {
        dop.id = index;
        dop.count = 1;

        referenceCol[index]->validRef = true;
    }

    it = orderedCol.insert(dop);
    referenceCol[index]->it = it;
}
```

The problem is that i'm having an error when i try to erase the iterator in the increment operation (look at the BOOM comment from the code).
The error i'm having is this:

"map/set erase iterator outside range"

The only thing that occurs to me is that maybe when erasing elements i may be invalidating other iterators, so those references doesn't hold any more, but i googled it and i found that for multiset, the erase operation only invalidate the erasing elements but no others... 
I also checked that in my running example i'm not erasing the element with the problematic index.

Please help! And sorry for my bad english!
Oh, and i'm open to suggestions about better strategies to accomplish the "refresh" of elements in order :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But isn't it a new iterator? I get a new one from the previous instruction: it = orderedCol.insert(dop);

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry for the noise.

Comment: How do you add elements to the `referenceCol` vector?

Comment: @AlanStokes i add all the elements i need in the SomeClass constructor with all the validReference set to false and without touching the iterator element at all. First i resize the collection to the number of elements and then i create the elements while iterating.

Comment: Have you checked that `decrementCount` is never called when `count` is already 0?

Comment: I just checked and in fact the error happens so early that it didn't call `decrementCount` at all :/

Comment: What does `DataCountSortingCriterion` look like?

Comment: It's a class which has the following operator: `bool operator() (const DataCount& p1, const DataCount& p2) const {
  return p1.count > p2.count;
 }`

Comment: If i try to compare the iterator i want to erase (it) with a new obtained iterator (with `advance()`) that holds the same `DataCount` element (when debuggin) i get the following error at the comparision: `"map/set iterators incompatible"`... i don't know if that helps.. the only other thing i can think of is that something is happening because when i create all the `DataReference` objects i leave the iterator reference unitialized... but then, i never use it until i know i have assigned it with some valid iterator!

Answer (score 0):

With only the code you've given us to debug I cannot be certain, but I suspect that you are calling `decrementCount(index)` such that `referenceCol[index]->validRef` is `false`. When this happens your decrementCount method simply calls erase on the iterator without checking validity.
If this were to happen on a formerly invalidated iterator you might see the behavior you're seeing.

As an aside here it appears that you should be using a multimap not a multiset. But again without understanding all of your code I can't say that for sure.

Comment: I know that it's impossible to infer this by the code i wrote, but i only call `decrementCount` if there is a valid reference. But i'm getting this error so early that my code don't even call `decrementCount` at all, and this is happening the first time the program calls `incrementCount` on an existing (valid) reference :/ About the multimap vs multiset, in my case all index are distinct and consecutive so i don't need to hash anything, that's why im using this approach.

Comment: Given this information I would say that the problem is that your `DataReference` class's default ctor is setting the `validRef` to true. And this is causing the if block of `incrementCount(index)` to be executed.